# Is 'Ilana' a Muslim name?

Tags: naming

Is 'Ilana إلانة'  a Muslim name?
It has origin in Hebrew. Is it proper for a Muslim?
It's meaning is to soften, to make more gentle, to make more lenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *Muslim name*. There are, however, two important guidelines to be used when naming people:

1- The name should not be offensive in any way.

> Narrated AbudDarda': The Prophet (peace_be_upon_him) said: On the Day
> of Resurrection you will be called by your names and by your father's
> names, so give yourselves good names.
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43#176)

2- The name should not imply *shirk*, i.e. it should not imply worship of anyone other than Allah. The famous *sahabi* Abu Huraira was named 'Abdu-Shams' (worshiper of the sun) before Islam. When he entered Islam, the Prophet changed it to Abdul-Rahman (worshiper of the Most Merciful).

The fact that it's in a language other than Arabic is not objectionable in any way. The names Moussa (Moses), Issa (Jesus), Ibraheem (Abraham) and many others are Hebrew and are quite proper.